# How to change date type year in string php?

Tags: php

```
echo $current_year = date("Y").'<br><br>';
echo $string_year = strftime("%Y", strtotime($current_year));
```

I want to change `date(Year)` to string but this code show output as `1970`.

I don't understand why it is `1970`?

How to make current year that is `2016`.
please help.

Comment: It's a problem with your server because `date("Y");` should return 2016

Comment: Why complicate things? Why not just do `echo  $string_year = strftime("%Y");` instead? When you get 1970, it would mean that the date was invalid, so it returns 01-01-1970.

Comment: please explain us what you see in first echo and second echo? what do you expect from strtotime('2016');

Comment: Is your problem with the first line of code only? Did you try `echo date('r')`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `strftime` function takes a `timestamp` as the second param but you are passing a string.

```
=> string strftime ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

Thus when you pass `date("Y").'<br>'` technically this is not a `timestamp` anymore and this defaults to the 1st year that our php works from being 1970.

When doing

```
echo $current_year = date("Y");
echo $string_year = strftime("%Y", strtotime($current_year));
```

I get `2016` but honestly I don't understand why you are asking for the year then changing it to a year again since both `$current_year` and `$string_year` are strings.

```
echo $current_year = date("Y");
echo $string_year = strftime("%Y", strtotime($current_year));

echo gettype( $current_year); //Output: string
echo gettype( $string_year);  //Output: string
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire date should be passed within strtotime(), and not just the year. Or you could simply pass the timestamp as the second parameter.

Try this:

```
echo $string_year = strftime("%Y", time());
```

OR

```
echo $string_year = strftime("%Y", strtotime("now"));
```